# php Multiple ORs and infinte loop

Tags: php, loops

The code below (thanks to Barman for help!) produces some random 'poetry'. The 'big' while-loop tests that the last line is of length comparable to the other lines.

It works fine, with the only problem that the last stanza is sometimes of fewer lines than the others. To fix this, I created the sections of the code that are commented-out: the `$laststanza` variable, and an additional `OR` condition in the big loop.

Adding these seems to produce an infinite loop, since it always exceeds my browser's run time on that line. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks!

```
<?php 

echo '<div id = shape>';

$sentences = array (
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur adipisicing elit. ",
"Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam. ",
"Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ",
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate. ",
"Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. ",
"Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. ",
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. ",
"Totam rem aperiam. ",
"Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. ",
"Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit. ",
"Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. ",
"Neque porro quisquam est. ",
"Qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur, adipisci velit. ",
"Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ",
"Ut enim ad minima veniam. ",
"Quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam. ",
"Nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? ",
"Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur. ",
"Vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? ",
);

$lastlen = null;
while ($lastlen == null OR ($wrapsize - $lastlen) > ($wrapsize / 10) /* OR $laststanza < $stanza_size */)
{ 
    $pick = rand(7,14);
    shuffle ($sentences);
    $key = 0;
    $fullstring = '';
    while ($key < $pick) 
        { $fullstring .= $sentences[$key];
            $key++; } 

    $wrapsize = rand (20, 70);
    $poemtext = wordwrap($fullstring, $wrapsize, "\n");
    $lines = explode ("\n", $poemtext);
    $count = count($lines);

    $lastkey = $count - 1 ; $lastline = $lines[$lastkey]; 
    $lastlen = strlen($lastline);
    $stanza_size = rand(2,4);

    // $laststanza = $count % $stanza_size;

    $key = 0; $i = 1;       
    $final = '';
    while ($key < $count) {
        if($i > 0 && $i % $stanza_size == 0) 
        {
        $final .= $lines[$key]."<br><br>";
        $key++; $i++;
        }
        else {
        $final .= $lines[$key]."<br>";
        $key++; $i++;
        }
    } 
}

echo $final;

echo '</div>'; //shape
?>
```

Comment: It seems that `$laststanza` will always be less than `$stanza_size` so your `while` condition will always evaluate to `TRUE`.

Comment: oh of course. I had confused myself with my variable names. When I saw what I had done, I changed `$laststanza` to `$leftover`. :) `OR $leftover > 0` works just fine. Thanks.